# Rails collection help. Not understandng how it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I have about 3 models that all relate to each other.

```
Class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base


  belongs_to :shipperline, foreign_key: 'receiver_quantity'


  def shippedqty
     Shipperline.getshippqty(@customerid).to_a.split
  end
```

Then i have a shipperline model

```
Class Shipperline < Activerecord::Base


has_many :invoices


def self.getshippqty(customerid)
  Shipperline.joins(:customerorderline, :shipper).select("cust_order_id").where(cust_order_id: customerid).order("shipped_qty").pluck(:shipped_qty).uniq
end
```

However in my form (which is on my main view because this query will usually return 4 to 5 results per invoice which is why i need a user to select which one it really belongs to.

So i have been trying

```
<%= form_for :invoice do |f| %>

<td id="putcolor"><%= f.select :shippedqty, Shipperline.getshippqty(@customerid).to_a.split %>  </td>

<% end %>
```

but it becomes empty. I have also tried collection_select and that dose not work either.

```
  <td id="putcolor"><%= f.collection_select :invoice_id, @shipqty, :id, :shippedqty %></td>
```

but then i get undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass

Can someone explain what im doing wrong or please point me in the right direction? I am fairly new to rails.

Also is there a better approach to trying to get a select box with these various results in it for the user to pick from?

Comment: Why do you split the array?

Comment: In ways i tried previous i seen it was an error and thought it might help if i split it.

Comment: Please go take a read through the guides, you're horribly, horribly lost! http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work much easier this way.

My Invoice_helper.rb

```
 def options_for_invoices(customerid)
      Invoice.shippedqty2(customerid)
 end

 def options_for_packlistid(customerid, shipqty)
      Shipperline.packlist(customerid, shipqty)
 end
```

Then in my form i did:

```
<%= form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :shippqty %>
    <%= f.select :shippedqty, options_for_invoices(@invoice.customerorderid) %>
    <br />
    <%= f.label(:packlistid %>
    <%= f.select :packlistid, options_for_packlistid(@invoice.customerorderid, @invoice.shippedqty) %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now when it shows a drop down collection with the correct values and inserts the correct values into the database for each record.